# How to add a Twig Tag in Symfony2?

Tags: php, templates, symfony, twig

I already learned [how to create a Twig extension](http://www.slideshare.net/weaverryan/being-dangerous-with-twig-symfony-live-paris).

But now I need to create a tag, because I want to do something like this:

```
{% singleline %}
<div>
    <script>
        function bla() {
            alert('bla');
        }
    </script>
</div>
{% endsingleline %}
```

Result:

```
<div><script>function bla() { alert('bla'); }</script></div>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by overriding `getTokenParsers()` method in your Twig Extension class, as described [here](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#id4).

To get a good example on how it's done, take a look at [Twig Extensions repository](https://github.com/fabpot/Twig-extensions).
Specifically, take [Debug](https://github.com/fabpot/Twig-extensions/blob/master/lib/Twig/Extensions/Extension/Debug.php) as an example (here's the [Twig_Extensions_TokenParser_Debug](https://github.com/fabpot/Twig-extensions/blob/master/lib/Twig/Extensions/TokenParser/Debug.php) class that's passed to the method).

**P.S.** That said, you should take a look at the note added to [Spaceless documentation page](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/spaceless.html) and maybe look into 3-rd party libraries like Tidy.

Comment: This won't remove the spaces and newlines inside script. Same for css and text, or basically anything enclosed by html tags.

Comment: @ChocoDeveloper yeah, you're right, sorry. I've updated my answer with proper information.